# php, how to convert an array containing stdClass Object into comma separated list

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

when I print_r $output I get the following

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => foo ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => bar ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => foobar ))
```

Im trying to do something which I though would be simple and convert the $output into

```
foo, bar, foobar
```

I have tried using for each statements such as below

```
foreach($array as $row){
   $new_array[$row['nid']] = $row['nid'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

but I just get invalid php.

I have tried ausing arraywalk and other examples here but not getting anything to work.

So how do I convert the following Array into a simple list of IDs?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the comma separated list, what you have should work in theory, but the code doesn't at all match your array. You state `$object` not `$array` and the property is `id` not `nid`.

However, just extract the `id` column and implode.  If you have PHP 7:

```
$list = implode(', ', array_column($output, 'id'));
```

For older versions:

```
$list = implode(', ', array_map(function($v) { return $v->id; }, $output));
```